# How to fade animate hide/show window with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, animation, fade

In Objective C, is it possible to hide my application window on launch, and then at some point of time make the call to do a pleasant fade animation to show my application window?

Not that you need to know this, but the background is that I was planning to do this from my Javascript in the webkit widget. I've already established the Objective C <==> Javascript bridge. So, when my charts finish loading, I make the call from Javascript back to Objective C to tell it to show the window with pleasant fade animation.

Here's what I've tried, but this has no fade effect -- the window just waits a sec (because those charts are loading) and then just pops on the screen fast. I tried changing the NSThread delay, but it didn't help -- that just slowed it more.

```
// ...in my app delegate...
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // NOTE THIS SAYS "WILL", NOT "DID" -- VERY IMPORTANT.
    // TO DO OTHERWISE WOULD GIVE YOU A WINDOW FLASH FOR A SECOND,
    // THEN FADE IN.
    [self hideWindow:_window];
}

- (void)hideWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    float alpha = 0.0;
    [window setAlphaValue:alpha];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

- (void)showWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    float alpha = 1.0;
    [window setAlphaValue:alpha];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

- (void)fadeOutWindow:(NSWindow*)window
{
    float alpha = 1.0;
    [window setAlphaValue:alpha];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        alpha -= 0.1;
        [window setAlphaValue:alpha];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.020];
    }
}

- (void)fadeInWindow:(NSWindow*)window
{
    float alpha = 0.0;
    [window setAlphaValue:alpha];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        alpha += 0.1;
        [window setAlphaValue:alpha];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.020];
    }
}

// My javascript to ObjC bridge calls this:
- (void)callShowAppWindow;
{
    [self fadeInWindow:_window];
}
```

Comment: Did you try to animate `alphaValue`?

Comment: Good point. I have updated the question with some source on what I've attempted so far. Instead of fading, it just pops on the screen unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my source on the question, I almost had it. Here's the fix on two functions that causes the fade effect:

```
- (void)fadeOutWindow:(NSWindow*)window
{
    float alpha = 1.0;
    [window setAlphaValue:alpha];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:1.5f];
    [[window animator] setAlphaValue:0.f];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
}

- (void)fadeInWindow:(NSWindow*)window
{
    float alpha = 0.0;
    [window setAlphaValue:alpha];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:1.5f];
    [[window animator] setAlphaValue:1.f];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `NSAnimationContext` animations to animate `alpha` property:

```
- (void)fadeInWindow:(NSWindow *)window {
    [window setAlphaValue:0.0];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
      [context setDuration:2.0];
      [window setAlphaValue: 1.0f];
    } completionHandler:^{ // or put nil instead of block
      NSLog(@"Completed");
    }]; 
}
```

And the same method to fade out your window:

```
- (void)fadeOutWindow:(NSWindow*)window {
    [window setAlphaValue:1.0f];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
      [context setDuration:2.0];
      [window setAlphaValue: 0.0f];
    } completionHandler:nil];
}
```

You can even combine this in one method:

```
- (void)fadeWindow:(NSWindow *)window in:(BOOL)in {
  [window setAlphaValue: in ? 0.0f : 1.0f];
  [window makeKeyAndOrderFront: self];
  [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup: ^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    [context setDuration: 2.0f]; // or whatever you need
    [window setAlphaValue: in ? 1.0f : 0.0f];
  } completionHandler: nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! The combined function is really neat. Although I had to use `[window.animator setAlphaValue:fadeIn ? 1.0 : 0.0];` instead of `[window setAlphaValue:fadeIn ? 1.0 : 0.0];` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding the window what about creating a splash/loading page occupying the initial window real estate and then doing some fancy animations with your actual window once your data has loaded or your app is ready to go?

Comment: Splash screens are so passé nowadays. Fewer and fewer apps have them.